# Audio not working on chromebook running Arch (EndeavourOS) with i3WM

Tags: audio, arch-linux, pulse-audio, i3-window-manager, pipewire

Although my audio was working fine when I first installed EndeavourOS on my Acer R11 chromebook two months ago, it stopped working 3 weeks ago. Since then, I have tried several things to get it back online, although my progress has been mostly limited to googling and trying things I find.

Before now, my experience with Linux has been limited to 1-2 years of mixed Ubuntu, WSL, chromebook Debian, and Manjaro. Manjaro was on the same device (chromebook R11) and audio worked as well there as it did at first here. Any testing I have done has returned no positive results. I am primarily hindered because of all of the i3wm audio dependencies: pulseaudio seems to be primarily used by "pipewire", which is itself a dependency for many more applications.

```
$ pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 3948
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: ochiruko
Host Name: dylan-cyan
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.77)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: auto_null
Default Source: auto_null.monitor
Cookie: 89df:a3ab
```

The interesting thing here is that the sink and source are both set to auto_null. I'm unsure of what that means, but I suspect that it indicates an issue with how PulseAudio detects audio devices. In addition, pavucontrol detects no devices other than its own dummy output.

How can I get the sound working again?

Comment: Hey @Dylan Sommer, welcome around! Out of curiosity... It may seem "stupid" but is there any card listed by `pactl list` ? What is the output of `sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*` ?